# Screen escape dollar sign

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen, quoting

I'm trying to run a command using `screen` which contains the dollar sign, but the dollar sign does not get through.

```
screen -d -m echo \$ > test.txt
```

`test.txt` just ends up being an empty file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redirecting the output of `screen`. That's why `test.txt` is empty.

In fact, the `$` is passed as an argument to `echo`. The shell you're calling screen from sees `\$`, resulting in the one-character string `$` being an argument of `echo`. Screen runs `echo` which displays a `$` in the screen window. Immediately after that, the program returns and so the window closes.

Note that if you want to use shell constructs for what is executed in the screen window, you'll need to invoke a shell explicitly.

```
screen -d -m sh -c 'echo \$ >test.txt'
```